# Pandas read_sql with chunksize: restart from a specific batch

Tags: python, sql, pandas, chunks

I'm trying to read a quite large SQL table with Pandas and save it to `.csv`. I'm using `chunksize` to save partial results.
The problem is that my connection sometimes gets interrupted.

Therefore, I would like to start saving the table from where I stopped.
I couldn't find a workaround to avoid loading the first chunks (skip all of those already saved).

I've tried to skip through the iterator with `next` but it doesn't seem to work.

**Note:** The SQL tables don't have an `ID` column.

My code so far:

```
# Read tables to save
tables = pd.read_csv('../data/to_extract.csv')

# Check which tables and batch have been saved already
all_files = os.listdir('../data')
batch_size = 10000

def save_chunk(chunk, db, table_name, batch_no):
    chunk.to_csv(f'../data/{db}.{table_name}_{batch_no:04d}.csv.zip',
                 compression={'method': 'zip',
                              'archive_name': f'{db}.{table_name}_{batch_no:04d}.csv'},
                 index=False,
                 )


def get_and_save_data(row):
    table_name = row['TABLE_NAME']
    db = row['TABLE_SCHEMA']

    batch_no = len(
        [i for i in all_files if i.startswith(f"{db}.{table_name}")])
    iterator = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {db}.{table_name}",
                                 cnxn, chunksize=batch_size)

    nb_chunk_to_get = int(np.floor(row.CURRENT_ROWS / batch_size) - batch_no)

    if batch_no > 0:
        chunk = next((x for i, x in enumerate(
            iterator) if i == batch_no), None) ## Here I try to skip to the batch I want
        save_chunk(chunk, rename_dict, db, table_name, batch_no)
        batch_no += 1

    for chunk in tqdm(iterator, total=nb_chunk_to_get, desc=f"{db}.{table_name}"):
        save_chunk(chunk, rename_dict, db, table_name, batch_no)
        batch_no += 1


rows_iter = (row for _, row in tables.iterrows())

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as pool:
    tqdm(pool.map(get_and_save_data, rows_iter),
         total=len(tables), desc='overall')
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to use `OFFSET n ROWS` in the SQL Query:

```
pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {db}.{table_name} OFFSET {offset} ROWS",
                                        cnxn, chunksize=batch_size)
```

Works like a charm!